# Move first half of posts to one parent page, second half to the other page

Tags: posts, customization, permalinks, homepage, development-strategy

there!

Let's assume that we have 2 posts (Post A, Post B). They already exist and located like following example.com/post-a

Now I want to create 2 separate parent pages like **cat1** and **cat2**.

How can I rearrange posts and get something like that:

- Post A: example.com/cat1/post-a
- Post B: example.com/cat2/post-b

And when I open example.com/cat1 I want to have list of post from cat1.

Comment: This sounds like a category archive, is there a reason you don't just use categories and `category.php`? What's the problem that this solves?

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, Just create two categories like cat1 and cat2. After that, you can assign categories from the Post A and Post B.

Then Wordpress creates the default URL Like this:

Post A: example.com/cat1/post-a
Post B: example.com/cat2/post-b